# Create Temporary tables with SQL Alchemy using textual statement (SQL Server)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to create Temporary tables using the `text()` construct (that is passed to the database mostly unchanged)?

The following Python code - using SQL Server - returns an Error: `This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

# DWH as User DSN (ODBC)
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DWH')

con = engine.connect()

sql_query_text = text(
"""
CREATE TABLE #employee
(
emp_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
hire_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
job_title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO #employee
VALUES ('Smith', 'James', '3/1/2016', 'Staff Accountant'),
('Williams', 'Roberta', '2/7/2004', 'Sr. Software Engineer'),
('Washington','Mark','8/19/2014', 'HelpDesk Technician');


SELECT * FROM #employee;
"""
)

rs = con.execute(sql_query_text)

# convert result to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall())

# Error
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError:
This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Comment: Perhaps try executing each part of the text separately.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your code block.